# Javascript function should be running on every page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I am looking at an asp.net 2 web application that I am maintaining (but did not write).

Some things that should happen on the page loading do not, but only sometimes, and it seems to be if you are using Firefox 3 inside a VM. JQuery and asp.net Ajax are used.

The important function that should run every time (but does not) is attached by the following Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){ Sys.Application.add_load(ImportantFunction); });   
$(document).ready(function(){ Otherstuff(); });
$(document).ready(function(){ MoreStuff(); });
//]]>
</script>
```

But if I use firebug to set a breakpoint inside ImportantFunction(), it is not hit on page load in firefox 3, but it is hit on an ajax update.

In the page there are multiple calls to $(document).ready since they come from different parts of the asp.net code behind it. Yes, they do all execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(ImportantFunction);   
$(document).ready(Otherstuff);
$(document).ready(MoreStuff);
//]]>
</script>
```

Put the call to `Sys.Application.add_load` in the body of `ImportantFunction`, i.e in your .js file:

```
function importantFunction()
{
   Sys.Application.add_load(ImportantFunction);
}
```

**Edit:** I'm not sure if its possible to add multiple functions to be run on `$(document).ready` event. It might help if you did this instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(init);   
    //]]>
    </script>
```

And in `init` you can include calls to all the other functions, i.e:

```
function init()
{
   importantFunction();
   otherStuff();
   moreStuff();
   //Any other functions to be called upon page load go here
}
```

It will also make the code easier to read :)

Comment: Give my example a shot anyway, it works for me so it could work for you too.

Comment: The posts that I have looked up indicate that you can attach more than one block of code to $(document).ready. http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/multiple-document-ready

Comment: Winner!. The inital hack fix looks like this:
$(document).ready(function(){ ImportantFunctionOnLoad(); }); 
function ImportantFunctionOnLoad() 
{ 
  ImportantFunction(); 
  Sys.Application.add_load(ImportantFunction); 
} 

need to clean up and make sure that ImportantFunction isn't called twice.

Comment: multiple $(document).ready() calls are allowed, they will all be executed.

Answer (score 6):

Is there any reason why you can't use the ASP.NET AJAX pageLoad function instead of $(document).ready()?

```
function pageLoad(sender, args)
{
     ImportantFunction();
     OtherStuff();
     MoreStuff();
}
```

This is part of the ASP.NET AJAX client page lifecycle and all JavaScript code inside will be executed on every page load, including asynchronous postbacks.

Answer (score 2):

You're using jQuery to attach a "load" method which then in-turn attaches a load event and I think this is where your problem is.

`$(document).ready` and `Sys.Application.add_load` are pretty much the same, or so my understanding goes. I'm not really sure in which order the browser will execute them though.

I'd suggest removing the `Sys.Application.add_load` wrapper call on `ImportantFunction` so you're not trying to attach to an event stack that has already fired.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [recent blog posting](http://www.tvidesign.co.uk/blog/sys.application.add_load-in-Firefox-3.aspx), this is a bug (or at least a misfeature) in FireFox 3.  He suggests naming your important function `PageLoad` to get it to work cross-browser, though I'm not sure if that will work or not.

Comment: That function is in a library and is called elsewhere, so I'm not going to rename it. But I could make a wrapper.