# Using ajaxToolkit CalendarExtender on an asp:label

Tags: asp.net

I'd like to use an ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender on an asp:Label. When I attach a CalendarExtender to the label, I get the error:

> Extender controls of type
>   'AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarExtender'
>   cannot extend controls of type
>   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label'.

I'm hoping someone knows a quick trick to allow me to display a date in a label and allow that label to be clicked to trigger/open a CalendarExtender which might target a hidden asp:TextBox... if that's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states, the Calendar extender is constrained to extend only textbox controls by default.

Looking at the [ASP.NET AJAX Control toolkit page for the Calendar extender](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/Calendar/Calendar.aspx), you should be able to use the `PopupButtonID` to enable the label to trigger the calendar popup (you'll need to add in the unhiding of the textbox too).

Comment: I think this would be perfect .. but it seems like making the asp:TextBox visible=false prevents the calendar from appearing.

Comment: That's because setting visible = false in the aspx markup does not output the HTML on the server side to render the textbox on the client side. I would put some JavaScript in the client side function pageLoad() to hide the textbox when the page has loaded

Comment: See here for the pageLoad - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416363/javascript-function-should-be-running-on-every-page-load/416447#416447 and 
http://encosia.com/2007/08/01/simplify-aspnet-ajax-client-side-page-initialization/

Comment: You'll want to set display = none on the textbox when the page has loaded

Answer (score 0):

If you have the source code of AjaxControlToolkit you can edit CalendarExtender.cs and then change

```
[TargetControlType(typeof(TextBox))]
```

and put Label (or Control if you want to have only one calendar extender) . Don't know how that will afect general behaviour of the Extender.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a textbox and then disable it